# Draw the set of points for which the product of the distances to two given points is equal to p < c^2/4

Tags: java, geometry, processing, computational-geometry

Two points are set on a horizontal line, the distance between which is `c`.
Draw the set of points for which the product of the distances to two given points is equal to `p < c^2/4`.

I have problem with this, because in the output I have line without points. I'm using Processing.

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  float c = 700;
  float p = (c * c) / 4;
  float x1 = (width - c) / 2;
  float x2 = x1 + c;
  float y = height / 2;
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  ellipse(x1, y, 10, 10);
  ellipse(x2, y, 10, 10);
  line(x1, y, x2, height / 2);
  strokeWeight(4);
  float threshold = 30.0; // Increased threshold for better visibility

  for (float x = x1; x <= x2; x += 1) {
    float d1 = dist(x, y, x1, y);
    float d2 = dist(x, y, x2, y);

    // Calculate the product of distances
    float product = d1 * d2;

    // Check if the product is equal to p and p < c^2/4
    if (abs(product - p) < threshold && p < (c * c) / 4) {
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      point(x, y);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  
}
```

I made the same task but with `p = c^2/4` like this:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  float c = 700;
  float p = (c * c)/4;
  float x1 = (width - c) / 2;
  float x2 = x1 + c;
  float y = height / 2;
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  ellipse(x1, y, 10, 10);
  ellipse(x2, y, 10, 10);
  line(x1, y, x2, height / 2);
  float threshold = 30.0; // Increased threshold for better visibility

  for (float x = x1; x <= x2; x += 1) {
    float d1 = dist(x, y, x1, y);
    float d2 = dist(x, y, x2, y);
    
    // Calculate the product of distances
    float product = d1 * d2;
    
    // Check if the product is within a certain range of p
    if (abs(product - p) < threshold) {
      stroke(255, 0, 0); 
      ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
}
```

I think it is working well. I have red points in the middle of the line. Then, I changed the requirements for `p<c^2/4` and it is not working. What might be the problem?

Comment: what do you think `p < (c * c) / 4` does in your `if` statement when your `p = (c * c) / 4` if I put aside your missing brackets then still `(c * c) / 4 < (c * c) / 4` is never true so you have no points rendered ... I assume the `p` should be the product of distances instead ... You are attempting to render the boundary `p == c*c/4` instead of interrior `p < c*c/4` so based on threshold and `p,c ` magnitudes rounding errors might cause to stop this working once your `p,c` got bigger. To remedy just increase `threshold` or compute its size as fraction of `c` value so it scale with size ...

Comment: Thank you very much, I made corrections, but still I can't see desired set of points.
I have changed this lines:
float p = dist(x1, y, x2, y);

float threshold = 0.2 * c;

if (d1 * d2 == p && p < (c * c) / 4) {
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      point(x, y);
    }

What might be the problem?

Comment: @Anon still the same error The `if` should be according to your description like this: `if (d1 * d2  < ((c * c) / 4))` where `d1,d2` are the distances between rendered point and two focal points (similar to ellipse) the result should be an oval or something similar to character `8` depending on the `c` value and distance between focal points ...

Comment: Also beware if you using pixels as units the values of `d1*d2` and `(c*c/4)` can get really big so using just `float` might still cause rounding errors with bigger `c` using `double` or  64bit integers is safer. Especially if you optimize out the `sqrt` from `d1,d2` for speed (on integers its a ~10x speed boost)

Comment: @user85421 can you please show your code with Java solution? I will try to run and debug it to better understand how to implement this in processing

Comment: @user85421 I tried to write this like this [link](https://github.com/afigonimus/geometry/blob/main/CustomPanel.java)
but I didn`t get the result I wanted

Comment: @user85421 The task I've described involves two fixed points on a horizontal line, with a constant distance between them - "c." I want to find the set of points on this line for which the product of the distances to these two given points is equal to a specific value, denoted as "p," where p < c^2/4.

Comment: @Spektre as you mentioned the result should be an oval or something similar to character 8 depending on the c value and distance between focal points, it seems that my task with p = c^2/4(i provided code in post) was wrong. In this case it should look like as task p<c^2/4?

Comment: @Anon only if your  `p = d1 * d2;`

Comment: @user85421 no `c` is constant similar to "radius" the OP definition is almost identical to ellipse defined by two focal points and length `c` with the difference that ellipse is `d1+d2 <= 2*c`  where `c` is major semi axis size and OP has `d1*d2 <= (c/2)*(c/2)` (s)he's code is aleady almost working the only stuff what needs to be changed is the condition to `if ((d1*d2)<=(c*c/4.0))` which I already commented before ... Your screenshot is different to what is the true result (but similar)

Comment: @Spektre and `c` is the distance between the two points, as specified in first sentence of the question (and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289538/draw-the-set-of-points-for-which-the-product-of-the-distances-to-two-given-point?noredirect=1#comment136282316_77289538)) - my screenshot is from code doing exactly as specified, additionally I added some coloring - there is at least one significant difference between `d1+d2 < 2*c` and `d1*d2 < c*c/4`

Comment: @user85421 and how did you get the result in the new screenshot? what have you changed in the code?

Comment: I tried to do the same task but with the requirement p == c^2/4. If I set if d== c^2/4, I have only a few points because the coordinates of the points that are multiplied to get d are limited to the number of decimal places, so with d=d1*d2, even with rounding d, there aren't many points with the value I need for d=c^2/4. 
I tried to solve this by using var d = Math.round(d1*d2);
                d  /= 10;
                d = Math.round(d);
                d *= 10;

But are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @user85421 You're right I missed that ... I used c  as input constant instead so I could achieve both ovals and 8 like shapes (however the 8 like shape was slightly different ) ... now with `c` as focal distance the shape will be always the same just scaled ...

Comment: I think you should find a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).